# JIRA REST API Create issue including "Components/s" field

Tags: rest, jira

I am trying create a JIRA through REST API, but while trying to add "Component/s" Field in the API, its not working.

```
curl -vvv -D- -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD -X POST --data '{"fields":{"project":{"key": "'"${PROJECT_KEY}"'"},"summary": "'"${PROJECT_SUMMARY}"'","assignee": {"name": "RAHUL"},{"update": {"components": [{"add": {"name": "DEV SUPPORT"}}]}},"description": "'"${PROJECT_DESCRIPTION}"'","issuetype": {"name": "Task"}}}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://jira.xyz.abc.com/rest/api/2/issue/
```

While executing this command, we are getting below error:

> {"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"components":"Field 'components' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown."}}

Could any faced these type of issues?

Answer (score 0):

The error is showing that the component is not on the proper screen, or the component is unknown.

I assume that you have a correct component, so it's not unknown.

Then you need to ensure it's in the proper screen: You need to go to the project settings and open the Fields tab. Then open the field configuration in the edit mode, find the Component Field and make the field visible. Or you can just follow the links in the permission helper.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `curl ...` command you provided. It looks like you'd like to add a new component to an issue.

So probably the screen that corresponds to "Edit Issue" doesn't have a "Component/s" field.

[image]

Try to add "Component/s" to the screen. Then your problem could be solved.